# Find command cannot be executed inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script to retrieve the last few days file info from the file system, and the file under some sub-folders will be excluded. Here is the script(test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
date_range=$1
base_dir=$2
excluded_dir=$3

# Command initialization
cmd="find $base_dir"
for item in ${excluded_dir[@]}
do
  cmd="$cmd -not \( -path '$base_dir/$item' -prune \)"
done
cmd="$cmd -type f -mtime -$date_range -ls"
echo $cmd

$cmd
```

I tried an example as below:

```
./test.sh 3 /root "excluded_folder1 excluded_folder2"
```

The command has been initialized as:

```
find /root -not \( -path '/root/excluded_folder1' -prune \) -not \( -path '/root/excluded_folder2' -prune \) -type f -mtime -3 -ls
```

If I run this `find` command in my terminal, it works fine, I can get the results that I want. While if it's executed in the bash script. I always get such an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: \(
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Does anybody knows what is the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the `\(` character being converted to just (.   You may need to use `\\(` when you build your cmd.  And the same for the `\)` of course.  On second thought, just replace `\(` with `(` in your quoted string and the same for `\)`.  The reason:  when you type the command at the shell prompt, you need the  backslash to escape the meaning of `(`.  However, when you have it quoted (as in your script) you do not need to escape the `(`.

Comment: See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Also, `excluded_dir` is not an array; there is no point using `${excluded_dir[@]}` when `$excluded_dir` produces the exact same expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers and suggestions I received here. But none of that solved my problem. The problem is finally solved by using 'eval' to execute the command. The final working bash script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
date_range=$1
base_dir=$2
excluded_dir=$3

# Command initialization
cmd="find $base_dir"
for item in ${excluded_dir[@]}
do
  cmd="$cmd -not \( -path '$base_dir/$item' -prune \)"
done
cmd="$cmd -type f -mtime -$date_range -ls"

eval $cmd
```

While there're some posts saying using `eval` in bash script is a bad and insecure choice, I still don't know how can I solve this problem with some other approaches. If someone got a better idea, please post it here.

Reference:

1. [What is the eval command in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash)
2. [Why and when should eval use be avoided in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score -1):

Based on my guess above, I suggest the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
date_range=$1
base_dir=$2
excluded_dir=$3

# Command initialization
cmd="find $base_dir"
for item in ${excluded_dir[@]}
do
  cmd="$cmd -not ( -path '$base_dir/$item' -prune )"
done
cmd="$cmd -type f -mtime -$date_range -ls"
echo $cmd

$cmd
```